# Finding address geographically?

Tags: qgis, geocoding, open-source-gis, software-recommendations

Is there a way to make Geocode or location address based on a shapefile streets, without using a web service and using QGIS or some open source software?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You have an address and a shapefile of streets and you want to find where the address is given your shapefile? What attributes does your shapefile have (like streetname, etc)? What format is your address query? Is it always precisely house number, street name, town?

Comment: Hi Manoel welcome to GIS.StackExchange. I would recommend reading through the "How do I ask a good question?" FAQ first: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can install PostgreSQL (opensource) and the PostGIS and TIGER extensions to load the US TIGER data.  [This post](http://dracodoc.github.io/2015/11/17/Geocoding/) has a lot of good info that I used to load the census data.

Then you can run SQL queries to get at the data or visualize it with QGIS.

I loaded all US Data into PostgreSQL on a Win 7 (64 bit) with 8 GB ram and a 230 GB hard-drive (with other apps installed)....  I am just about of of space though with the US data taking up around 100 GB.

For other countries, you'll probably need to search and see what others are doing.

Answer (score 0):

The **MMQGIS Plugin** has a 'Geocode from Street Layer' tool that you can use to geocode locations against your streets data.

You can point to a CSV file of locations you want to geocode.

Then you set the parameters of the geocoding - really setting the fields in your source data that contain the street segment attributes needed to geocode.